# jQuery display message

Tags: jquery

How to with jQuery display message after clicking submit button, delay message box for example 10 secund and then send the data form.

Or send the data form after clicking "ok" button in message box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On submitting, this pops up a js confirm box.

```
$('.form').submit(function() {
    return confirm('Are you sure you want to submit this form');
});
```

Comment: and where is delay message function?

Comment: For delay, use the [setTimeout()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) method.

Answer (score 0):

I did the same thing to, but I used the jQuery Plugin Modal Popup 
 http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal/

And what I did was

```
        $('#submitForm').live("click",function(){
                $.modal("<h1>Thank you for submitting</h1>");
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('#simplemodal-overlay').remove();
                    $('#simplemodal-container').remove();
                    //window.location.replace("http://www.google.at"); go to custom URL
                },2000);                
        });
```

So this simply shows the modal when you click the submit Button

```
<input id="submitForm"type="button" name="Progress" value="Submit"></input>
```

and than simply remove the modal pop up again and delay this action by 2 seconds !